ArcGIS Pro Failed to publish raster layer to the web
I would like to publish a raster layer to the ArcGIS Online map. I've done the georeference and next followed the video below:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bQmOpcJrf0c&ab_channel=EsriCanada
Unfortunately when I approach the very last step, which is publishing the layer by the Share Package tool, I got the following error:
ERROR 002934: Failed to publish web layer.
The ESRI says, that the reason of failure is undefined!
https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/tool-errors-and-warnings/001001-010000/tool-errors-and-warnings-02926-02950-002934.htm
I just want to make the map tile with simple floorplan, which looks like below:
Does anyone have the similar problem? Is there any minimum scale which should be put here or what?

your using Web Mercator for an inside drawing plan? Esri has https://www.esri.com/en-us/arcgis/products/arcgis-indoors/license-levels/maps for indoor mapa

I use the standard ArcGIS Pro. Prior to exporting, I put 2 points of georeferencing. If the floorplan covers (let's say) 2kmx1km then it works fine. Since I try to confine it to the size of the building it throws the error.
